# Use modern android themes with old API

Tags: android, android-spinner

Now I have my spinner theme like this:

[image]

I am writing an app with `android:minSdkVersion="7"`.
I want to set spinner theme like spinner in Theme.Holo.Light.

[image]

Can I achieve this, and if I can, can you explain me steps that I should take?

When I try to just replace spinner theme with Holo, Eclipse starts telling me that I can't do it because of min api for this spinner style is 7 and it should be 11.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/meter_place_view_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use library which ports Holo theme for old devices. Try [HoloEverythere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)